# OneToMany Create Fails with InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, transient, hibernate-onetomany

I am fairly new to Hibernate and have been using the manual & online forums, but I am stumped on this issue.  I’m using Spring 3.2 with Hibernate 4 & Annotations.  I have a parent (PledgeForm) & child (PledgeFormGiftLevel) table that is one-to-many.

**Domain/Models:
Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PLEDGE_FORMS")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PledgeForm implements Serializable {

static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PledgeForm.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="pledge_form_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pledge_form_seq", sequenceName="PLEDGE_FORM_SEQ")
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer id;

….

@OneToMany(mappedBy="pledgeForm", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)//********1
private List<PledgeFormGiftLevel> pledgeFormGiftLevels = new ArrayList<PledgeFormGiftLevel>();

….

public List<PledgeFormGiftLevel> getPledgeFormGiftLevels() {
   return this.pledgeFormGiftLevels;
}

public void setPledgeFormGiftLevels(List<PledgeFormGiftLevel> pledgeFormGiftLevels) {
   this.pledgeFormGiftLevels = pledgeFormGiftLevels;
}

//I do not think the following method is needed, but I decided to try it just in case
public void addPledgeFormGiftLevels(PledgeFormGiftLevel pledgeFormGiftLevels) {
   pledgeFormGiftLevels.setPledgeForm(this);
   getPledgeFormGiftLevels().add(pledgeFormGiftLevels);
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PLEDGE_FORM_GIFT_LEVELS")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pledge_form_gift_level_seq", sequenceName="PLEDGE_FORM_GIFT_LEVEL_SEQ")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PledgeFormGiftLevel implements Serializable {

static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PledgeFormGiftLevel.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="pledge_form_gift_level_seq")
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer id; 

…

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)//yes?
@JoinColumn(name="PLEDGE_FORM_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable=true, updatable=true)//yes?
private PledgeForm pledgeForm = new PledgeForm();

…

public PledgeForm getPledgeForm() {
   return pledgeForm;
}
public void setPledgeForm(PledgeForm pledgeForm) {
   this.pledgeForm = pledgeForm;
}
```

**Controller (there is a graphic, so I have code to pull in the file):**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("pledgeForm")
public class PledgeFormController {
   @Autowired
   org.unctv.service.PledgeFormManager Service;

…

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveJdbcPledgeForm", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="save")
public ModelAndView save(
   @ModelAttribute("pledgeForm")
   @Valid PledgeForm pledgeForm, BindingResult result,
   @RequestParam("logoImg") MultipartFile file,
   @RequestParam(value="removeLogoImg", required=false) String removeLogoImg) throws Exception {

      ModelAndView mav = null;
      mav = new ModelAndView("pledgeFormSearch");//Name of the JSP

      if (removeLogoImg != null) {
         pledgeForm.setLogoFilename(null);

         pledgeForm.setLogoImg(null);
         pledgeForm.setLogoContentType(null);
      } else if (file != null && file.getBytes().length > 0) {
         pledgeForm.setLogoFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
         pledgeForm.setLogoImg(file.getBytes());
         pledgeForm.setLogoContentType(file.getContentType());
      }

      Service.save(pledgeForm);
      mav.addObject("pledgeForm", pledgeForm);//JSP Form's Command Name (pledgeForm); 
      mav.addObject("cmdName", "pledgeForm");
      mav.addObject("actionType", "Save");
      return mav;
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service("simplePledgeFormManager")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class SimplePledgeFormManager implements PledgeFormManager { 
   @Autowired
   private HibernatePledgeFormDao hibernatePledgeFormDao;


…

@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void save(PledgeForm pledgeForm) throws Exception {
   hibernatePledgeFormDao.save(pledgeForm);
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Repository("PledgeFormDAO")
public class HibernatePledgeFormDao implements PledgeFormDao {

static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernatePledgeFormDao.class);

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


...

@Override
public void save(PledgeForm pledgeForm) throws Exception {
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(pledgeForm);
}
```

Using the code above, parent/child records can be selected and updated fine.  When I display the “trace” messages from hibernate, the update does have this trace message about the child, though:

```
[2013-12-06 10:31:24,648] TRACE Persistent instance of: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeFormGiftLevel
[2013-12-06 10:31:24,649] TRACE Ignoring persistent instance
[2013-12-06 10:31:24,649] TRACE Object already associated with session: [org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeFormGiftLevel#1]
```

The create always gives this error if there is a child record:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm
```

When I look at the hibernate logs, I see that it updates the parent & the child based on transient objects.  Then it tries to flush & finds a persistent copy of the child, so it rolls back everything.

```
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] TRACE Automatically flushing session
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] TRACE Flushing session
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] DEBUG Processing flush-time cascades
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] TRACE Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] TRACE Cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm.pledgeFormGiftLevels
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,615] TRACE Cascading to save or update: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeFormGiftLevel
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,616] TRACE Persistent instance of: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeFormGiftLevel
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,616] TRACE Ignoring persistent instance
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,616] TRACE Object already associated with session: [org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeFormGiftLevel#51]
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,616] TRACE Done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm.pledgeFormGiftLevels
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,616] TRACE Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,617] DEBUG Dirty checking collections
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,617] TRACE Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,617] DEBUG Collection found: [org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm.pledgeFormGiftLevels#51], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,618] DEBUG rolling back
[2013-12-06 10:34:13,618] DEBUG rolled JDBC Connection
```

The Hibernate documentation shows this as even simpler than I my code is, but I had to add the fetch & cascade values.  I’ve played with changing the fetch & cascade values & placement (starting with the Hibernate documentation & then adding on), but everything else I try still causes the create to fail & often causes the update to fail too.

Many forum posts that I find show flush() or evict().  I am not certain if it is Hibernate 4 or annotations (@Transactional, I think) I’m using, but I do not see a place for that in my code.  From the Hibernate trace logs, I can see that flushing is occurring automatically with in the saveOrUpdate() method.

I also tried dropping the tables & sequences & starting fresh.

Any advice about getting the create to work is appreciated.  If you can point me to specific documentation that I missed, that is appreciated as well.

Thanks,
Bonnie

Comment: Just a quick note.  Java variable names are lowercase.  So `org.unctv.service.PledgeFormManager Service;` should be `org.unctv.service.PledgeFormManager service;`  If there were an actual `Service` class with static methods that could cause issues.  I suspect that is why you are using the fully qualified name.  Is there another `Service` class?

Comment: Does the `PledgeForm` come back from the UI with a `PledgeFormGiftLevel` set?

Comment: @KevinBowersox, thanks for the tips.  

I used this tutorial when learning Spring -- http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/spring-framework-tutorial/developing-a-spring-3-framework-mvc-application-step-by-step-tutorial/ -- and I got the capital Service from that.  I actually assumed it was a special Spring thing to have that be capitalized.  I can make that change.  There is no static class called Service within my project.

Comment: @KevinBowersox  On update, the PledgeForm comes back with the PledgeFormGift level set (and properly updated).  On create, neither is saved to the database because of the rollback.  The hibernate logs do show that the PledgeForm gets saved and then it finds the PlegdeFormGiftLevel and also saves that.  Just after saving the PledgeForm, I see this trace message & then it goes on to do the save:
Wrapped collection in role:org.unctv.domainmodel.PledgeForm.pledgeFormGiftLevels
Is that what you were asking?

Comment: What I was concerned about was that the `PledgeFormGiftLevel`s in the `PledgeForm`'s `List<PledgeFormGiftLevel>` had their `PledgeForm` field set to the `PledgeForm`.  In a bidirectional relationship you are responsible for managing both sides of the entity.  So if you create a `PledgeFormGiftLevel` and add it to `PledgeForm`'s list, you need to make sure each instance of `PledgeFormGiftLevel` has their `PledgeForm` property set.

Comment: I had this code in my answer but removed it because I think `hashcode` & `equals` will do the trick.  I'll add it back just in case.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I see, you are talking about the addPledgeFormGiftLevels() method, right?  I recently added that based on the Bidirectional Mapping section on this site: http://lifeinide.blogspot.com/2010/11/hibernate-parent-child-and-annotations.html.  Before that I didn't have that method at all.  The results are the same with or without it, and I suspect that it is not being called.  I left it there because I am not certain that it is not needed.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Okay, thanks for all the help.  The hashcode and equals generators are new to me, so I am looking into that now.  I'll post back when I get that tested.

Comment: Hope things work out well.  `hashcode` and `equals` are used by ORM frameworks to determine equality.  So if an entity is stored in your persistence context and then you create the entity in another part of your application (like having Spring bind a ModelAttribute) the ORM framework cannot determine if they are the same entity by traditional means, such as comparing if the instances are in the same spot in memory.  It needs to compare the information in both entities and use that information to determine equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that `equals` and `hashcode` have not been overridden in the entities.  These methods are used to compare objects to determine their equality.  Hibernate may not be able to determine if an existing instance of the entity exists without these methods being overridden.  Try providing implementations for `hashcode` and `equals`.

If your using Eclipse, press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `S`, `H` to bring up the dialog for creating the `hashcode` and `equals` methods.  Pick fields that contain values that are relatively unchanged and then generate the methods.

Also be sure that you are managing both sides of the entity as discussed in the above comments:

```
public ModelAndView save(
   @ModelAttribute("pledgeForm")
   @Valid PledgeForm pledgeForm, BindingResult result,
   @RequestParam("logoImg") MultipartFile file,
   @RequestParam(value="removeLogoImg", required=false) String removeLogoImg) throws Exception {

      ModelAndView mav = null;
      mav = new ModelAndView("pledgeFormSearch");//Name of the JSP

      //Manage both sides of the entity
      List<PledgeFormGiftLevel> levels = pledgeForm.getPledgeFormGiftLevels();

      for(PledgeFormGiftLevel level: levels){
          level.setPledgeForm(pledgeForm);
      }

      if (removeLogoImg != null) {
         pledgeForm.setLogoFilename(null);

         pledgeForm.setLogoImg(null);
         pledgeForm.setLogoContentType(null);
      } else if (file != null && file.getBytes().length > 0) {
         pledgeForm.setLogoFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
         pledgeForm.setLogoImg(file.getBytes());
         pledgeForm.setLogoContentType(file.getContentType());
      }

      Service.save(pledgeForm);
      mav.addObject("pledgeForm", pledgeForm);//JSP Form's Command Name (pledgeForm); 
      mav.addObject("cmdName", "pledgeForm");
      mav.addObject("actionType", "Save");
      return mav;
}
```

Comment: The "Manage both sides of the entity" code that you listed above made it work.  Thank you so much.  I felt that I needed to explicitly set the child values in the parent's array, but I didn't know where to get them from.  It never occurred to me to pull them from the parent itself.  I am still working on figuring out the hashcode and equals, but I will go ahead & accept your answer.  I really appreciate the very clear help as well as the other advice you offered.

Comment: @BonnieSmyre Excellent!  I believe the hashcode and equals methods will come in to play when performing an update an entity.  Was your current case an insert?

Comment: Actually, the update was already working & still works.  It was the insert that was giving me problems.